# what is the taglib of display header in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl, displaytag

I am using Spring 2.5 mvc. I export data from database into excel. I did everything but when I try to use  display header like below

```
<display:header>
   <thead id="aaa">
       <tr>

        </tr>
    </thead>
 </display:header>
```

it gives me an taglib error
 I added this taglib.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net"%>
```

Apart from this taglib, is there anything that I must use? Especially display:header.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There is no `display:header`.
See docs [here](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html).

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem. Yes, there is `<display:header>`. However, I had used displaytag-1.1.1.jar first. Instead of this jar, I used displaytag-1.2.jar and problem has been solved.
Regards,